# What are these white insects on Areca palm? What should I do about them?

Tags: identification, houseplants, insects, palm

[image]
[image]

My first thought was mealybugs. But aren’t these too tiny to be mealybugs. I don’t see any big ones.

I see them quite a lot on different leaves. What should I do about it? Is it best to throw the plant out to prevent it spreading to other plants?

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of scale and they are hard to get rid of. Basic controls are:

- remove heavily infested fronds by cutting them at the base
- get a cloth soaked in one liter of water to 5 ml of dish soap and wipe down all the fronds, wait a minute or two
- wipe or shower the plant to remove the soap as it can burn the leaves if it gets too thick
- repeat at five to six day intervals at least twice.
- restart the treatment if new scale is found

Comment: Thanks for that! That is very helpful! Is there a risk of it spreading to other plants?

Comment: @ag14 only if there get to be a lot of them on the plant.  Then, mature adults can be born with wings to move to new plants.  If you treat the plant now you should be fine